# Is it possible to use a variable inside a PHP function without passing it?

Tags: php, function, variables

So I'm creating my own personal calendar web app and I'm running into an issue with variables within a function. At the moment my app starts with pulling the time and finding out the month, day, and year of today's date.

```
$year = date("Y",time());
$today = date("j",time());
$month = date("m",time());
```

Later in the app I have a function to "draw" each calendar square.

```
function thisDay($input) {
    date("m",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$input,$year));
    echo //html stuff here;    
}
```

Now I can pass all three variables ($month,$input,$year) because I'm using the function in a while loop.  But I've run into this before in other projects I've worked on.  I have a function to make my life easier, but I keep having to pass a half dozen variables each time I use the function even though some of them rarely change.

Comment: You can probably using a Bean class (The class with getters and setters) and assign all the values there and pass just the object.

Comment: Then maybe you are looking for classes and objects!

Comment: You can declare the variables as `global` inside the function, but this is a very messy way to do things. Passing the variables may seem a pain, but it's clear where the variables originate.

Comment: This is where classes and encapsulation would be a very good idea. A quick, ugly solution is to use the `global` keyword but this will cause more pain down the line

Comment: @MikeW please please don't advise to use globals. PHP is a mess enough as it is.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Read my comment again. I advised exactly the opposite.

Comment: @MikeW don't even *mention* globals. It is the **wrong** way of doing it, not just "very messy".

Comment: @BartFriederichs: How about answering how to do it, then?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Sometimes the pedantry on this site really gets on my nerves. Sorry to have offended your sensibilities, but I notice that a number of other contributors have mentioned globals. It's one method, and the OP will find it anyway. I agree it's not a good method, but trying to pretend it doesn't exist is reminiscent of Canute on the beach.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I see you're running around leaving comments about how we shouldn't even mention globals. I feel it is much better to explicitly point out that globals are a bad idea, than just not even mention them.

Comment: I'm guessing it's @BartFriederichs who downvoted my answer, then.
It's like plugging up your ears singing "LALALALALA" as loud as you can...

Comment: You're building a application designed around dates and times, so why aren't you using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime)?  That pretty much solves your problem right there.

Comment: @Cerbrus, yes I was one of them. And I think advising people to do wrong things is bad. Tell them to not use globals and why. I was wrong to say not to mention them. They should be mentioned as being the way not to do things in a clear and concise way. They should certainly not be mentioned as a viable way of handling this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a class with all the data you use to pass, you have a few benefits:

- You don't have a long list of parameters to handle
- The list of parameters could change, you just change that class, and you dont need to change the functions signature
- You have all the related data together

```
class MyDate {
  public $year,$month, $day;
}


function anyFunction(MyDate $date) {
   //here you can use $date->day, $date->month, or $date->year
}
```

UPDATE:

As you can read in the comments, using  `DateTime` class would already be enough, but what i understand, is that you have this issue in diferent moments in your projects, so this is a good generic approach so you can solve all those situations.

Comment: Thanks ;) Those lists can be a little buggy when you need a code block after it.

Comment: yeah, i was editing it with "here is the code", but your way is better!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could bypass the need to pass in variables to your function by using globals, but that is a much worse situation to be in.

Instead define an class that represents your data, and pass instances of that class.

Something like:

```
class My_Date {
  public $year;
  public $today;
  public $month;

  // ...any methods you need
}
```

Then, you can create an instance of this class, and just pass that instance:

```
$my_date = new My_Date();
$my_date->year = date("Y",time());
$my_date->today = .... // and so on.

// then call your function:
my_function($my_date); // just pass the single argument
```

(Name your class better, and you might want to change the visibility of the data members depending on your needs)

Comment: Don't use globals for this kind of design. It is **wrong**.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Where am I using globals?

Comment: You start with saying "you could ... use globals".

Comment: Did you miss the part where I explicitly state: "but that is a much worse situation to be in.", and then proceed to explain a better way to do it?

Comment: No. Just remove the entire talk about globals. No need to refer to it.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: You **can't** ignore the fact globals exist. People new to PHP **will** find it. It's better to tell'm not to use it than to let them figure it out on their own. Then they'll just use it, since it's easy.

Comment: @BartFriederichs No, I won't do that because I would much rather explain to OP that globals are bad design, than just pretend they don't exist. We're here to teach better programming practices, and part of that includes pointing out bad design.

Comment: Using a class is a very good idea, but why not using an instance of `DateTime` where everything useful is already attached?

Comment: @Sven: In this particular case, yes, an instance of `DateTime` would suffice.\

Comment: @xbonez OK. I'd change the sentence to "don't use globals", be clear and concise instead of slightly sarcastic. But it's your answer, so it's up to you.

Comment: *"but that is a much worse situation to be in."* is hardly sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

Globals will do the trick but are generally good to stay away from. In larger programs you can't be certain of there behaviour because they can be changed anywhere in the entire program. And testing code that uses globals becomes very hard.

An alternative is to use a class.

```
class Test {
        private $year = date("Y",time());
        private $today = date("j",time());
        private $month = date("m",time());

        public function thisDay() {
            //do your stuff
        }
    }

    $obj = new Test();
    $newvalue = $obj->thisDay();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can accsess to variables by using `&`.
Something like that:

```
function thisDay($input) {
date("m",mktime(0,0,0,&$month,$input,&$year));
echo /*html stuff here*/; }
```

BUT be cautious while using this. If you intend to change values of this variables in this function then keep in mind that you will change its value directly in memory.

Comment: Eh, no, that's not how [value references work](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).